# Spring JMS - standalone durable topic subscriber

Tags: java, spring, jms, scheduled-tasks

I need to create a job that will run every 5 minutes (5 minutes from its last run), receive some messages from a topic and process them. This has to be a standalone Java application.

I have considered two options. I am stuck with both of them -

1. Use Spring's JmsTemplate. I am not sure how to create a durable subscriber with JmsTemplate?
2. Use DefaultMessageListenerContainer which provides facility to create a durable subscriber. But I am not sure how to gracefully shutdown such an application after a given period of time say 2 minutes.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I need to use our standard enterprise scheduler - Control M. I will not be allowed to use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: Is there any specific requirement that you need a explicit scheduler. The DefaultMessageListener starts listening for message once you start your app(otherwise there is no point in using defaultmessagelistener, how would you know that you have picked up all the messages.?). I don't find any specific reason, until unless you have acute shortage of resources to go for scheduler

Comment: I can't create a standalone application that will run forever (based on DMLC) and put it in production because we don't have monitoring capabilities to monitor such apps. So, I have been asked to create a frequently scheduled job and the scheduler has to be our standard enterprise scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You need two pieces:

1. The scheduled job that runs every X minutes: connects to the queue and sends a message.
2. The listener, running on a JMS host of some kind, that takes messages off the queue/topic.

What JMS host do you plan to use?  JBOSS?  OpenJMS?  RabbitMQ?  Something else?

Will the client job be a Java main that executes a scheduled ExcecutorTask in a while loop?

Comment: ActiveMQ. The main method will call some internal services that will do some processing with data from the message payload.